# Maven Wildfly Plugin : Deployment to tmp directory

Tags: maven, deployment, wildfly

I'm using the wildfly-maven-plugin for the deployment and call

```
mvn clean package wildfly:deploy
```

Since the deployment always goes into the directory standalone/tmp I'm a little bit confused. I expected that the deployed war should go to standalone/deployments. What configuration do I have to change so that the war is deployed to standalone/deployment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Maven WildFly Plugin deploys the application through the management/administration interface (by default running on port 9990). The alternative for deployment is copying the application artifact directly to the standalone/deployments directory.

The Maven WildFly Plugin only uses the first approach (management interface) which is cleaner in my opinion. If you want to deploy by copying it to the 'deployments' directory you wouldn't need the Maven plugin at all. For local deployments you can use a simple copy, for remote deployments you would need SCP or a similar technique applicable for your OS/environment.